# oh-my-posh won't activate when starting up terminal, but if I refresh .bashrc it activates

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bashrc

Upon starting the terminal:

[image]

But if I run .bashrc it works:

[image]

I'm not sure why when .bashrc runs on startup it doesnt work, but if I run it myself it works.

Edit : I found a solution that worked
I was putting

```
eval "$(oh-my-posh --init --shell bash --config ~/jv_sitecorian.omp.json)"
```

inside of ~/.bashrc but I needed to put it into ~/.profile

Answer (score 0):

Check if `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin` is part of your path. It was my problem here, after adding it to the PATH before calling the eval function in `.bashrc`, it now works right when I log in.